# Axios not failing when device is offline in vue.js

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, axios, nativescript

I have a nativescript vue.js application that is hitting an endpoint to get a token when the user clicks login using axios.

when the emulator phone is offline the axios call is still made and the then is executed as if there was a successful request made, looking at the network tab there is a request made but it is pending forever and the axios call returns immediately.

if I run axios in a browser based application it does not seem to fail in the same way.

This is my calling code for:

```
   methods:{
            submit()
                { this.axios.post('https://backendauth.free.beeceptor.com/api/login',this.user)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('Detected as a success')
                    console.log(response.status)
                    console.log(response)
                    console.log(response.data.success.token)
                    this.data = JSON.stringify(response.data)
                    this.$navigateTo(this.$router['home'])
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    if (err.response.status === 401) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log(err.response)
                    }

                    })
                this.submitting = 'form clicked'
            }
```

I have created a repo that demonstrates this

https://github.com/jachno/basicAuth

This image shows the console request being successful with the device online

[image: Working Request]

and this shows the call working over the network

[image: Network call]

And this shows the network pending request when it is in flight mode

[image]

This now shows what the console looks like when the device in in flight mode:

[image: Console with Flight mode enabled]

Answer (score 4):

When the Http call fails, the status is set to `null`, Axios considers that as a success. So the workaround could be verifying whether your status is `null`, on your success callback. If it's `null`, then consider it as failure.

You may also check whether [connectivity](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity) is set to none, to find out whether your device is really offline.

You might want to raise a bug in the [Github repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues) regarding this.